# My animation (hover out) doesn't work and I don't understand why

Tags: css

I'm actually working on Wordpress for a website. 
I want my grid to display a description when hovering an image but the animation of the text fading out isn't working and I don't understand why.

I'm totally new to CSS so it might be a basic error, on internet i saw that we should put the out animation on the same element without the over, I tried without ".text-a-hover" (always in .el-item) and tryed to put it directly in the .texte-a-hover but neither worked

```css
.texte-a-hover {
  border: 2px;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.el-item .texte-a-hover {
  animation: out 0.5s;
}

.el-item:hover .texte-a-hover {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: in 0.5s;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

@keyframes in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="texte-a-hover"> text </p>
```

.el-item is the whole group, image + text

So i expect the text to fade out just like it fade in

Thanks for the attention you are paying to me and for your futur help

Comment: Can you include your html too? And there is some bits missing from your css

Comment: Please provide a complete code runable or at least an image.

Comment: I'm using a theme on wordpress that is very huge css, I don't know what to pick :x

Answer (score 1):

Keyframes seem a bit overkill here. You can just use the :hover state and some transitions for elements.

```css
.texte-a-hover {
  border: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, height .5s;
}

.el-item:hover .texte-a-hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-item">XXX
  <p class="texte-a-hover"> text </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. For animating hover effects it would be best if you used `transitions` instead of `animations`. Here is the effect you are trying to accomplish using transitions, for example:

```
.texte-a-hover {
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.texte-a-hover:hover {
  transform:translateY(-30px); // example property change
  height:auto;
}
```

In the example above, you simply add the `transition` property and set it up according to your needs (in this case apply transition for **all** properties, for **0.5 second** and **ease** easing) and then just change your property on `hover`.

Comment: thanks you, That worked fine ! (I picked a bit from all answers)

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually need to use `@keyframes` for something this simple. I think `transition` would be your best bet. I've created an example for you below just using the `transition` property on `:hover` of the `.el-item`.

You just set the default properties of the `.texte-a-hover` to what it should look like when it is not in the hover state, then when add a `:hover` and these properties will overwrite the default ones when you hover on your selected item.

Here is a simple example:

```css
.el-item {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: turquoise;
  position: relative;
}

.texte-a-hover {
  transition: 0.35s;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.el-item:hover .texte-a-hover {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-item">
  <p class="texte-a-hover">text</p>
</div>
```

Depending what kind of style you want, you can just adjust the styling of the overlay. Here is a more styled version:

```css
.el-item {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) center/cover no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.texte-a-hover {
  transition: opacity 1s, top 0.35s;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.el-item:hover .texte-a-hover {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-item">
  <p class="texte-a-hover">your description goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec scelerisque quis justo non accumsan. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks you, That worked fine ! (I picked a bit from all answers)